# How to resolve the Pod install error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, installation, cocoapods

While I install the Pod. It shows the error like this. How to solve this?

> Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the 
>       future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not 
>       using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

I found a solution like this:

```
$ cd <parentDirectory of Podfile>
$ open -a Xcode Podfile`
```

If I put it like this, it shows the error:

> “Podfile” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please edit your Podfile in Xcode.

Open your Podfile in Xcode.
Edit it.
Save it.

When you use TextEdit for Pod file editing

```
pod ‘Fabric’, ‘~> 1.7.1′    //notice the quotes
```

Open Podfile with Xcode.

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.1'  //notice the quotes
```

Remove `Podfile.lock` from folder.

Close Xcode Project.

Perform `pod install`.

Open `ProjectName.xcworkspace` file.

Comment: Please Tell me clearly am a newbie to iOS.I have opened my `podfile` in my `Xcode`.In that what i have to edit and save.

Comment: Just check quotes in podfile, If quotes looks slightly crossed then remove it and add it. It should looks like Second case in Answer.

Comment: If this answer find helpful, then please mark it as accepted, so other will find it helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please post screenshot of error logs from terminal. So i will get idea.